# c# - x509 certificate no lo reconoce en windows server 2008 R2

Tags: c#, .net

estoy intentando acceder al almacen de certificados en un server 2008 R2 y me dice

```
clientCertStore.Certificates.Count = 0
```

La misma petición con el mismo certificado en mi localhost si me lo devuelve, la única diferencia es que mi PC es un W7.

La instalación del certificado se ha hecho de la misma manera en ambas máquinas, con clave exportable y en el almacen Personal.

No se si tendrá que ver, pero el certificado está caducado, pero como digo, en mi PC si que me  lo devuelve.

```
private X509Certificate2 Certificate(string nif) 
{
    X509Certificate2 cert = null;
    X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser); 
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly); 
    X509CertificateCollection certs = store.Certificates; 
    int c = certs.Count; 
    foreach (X509Certificate2 cert_aux in certs) 
    { 
        if (cert_aux.SubjectName.Name.Contains(nif.ToUpper())) 
        {
            cert = cert_aux; break; 
        }
    }

    store.Close(); 
    return cert;
}
```

Comment: Hola, deberías editar tu pregunta para mostrar el código de cómo generas `clientCertStore`. También verifica que el certificado esté bien instalado y tenga el certification path completo. Saludos

Comment: Gracias @Sergio. Este es mi código:

Comment: Gracias @Sergio. Este es mi código: Gracias @Sergio. Este es mi código: `private X509Certificate2 Certificate(string nif)
{X509Certificate2 cert = null;X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
X509CertificateCollection certs = store.Certificates;
int c = certs.Count;              
foreach (X509Certificate2 cert_aux in certs)
{ if (cert_aux.SubjectName.Name.Contains(nif.ToUpper()))
{cert = cert_aux;  break; }} store.Close();  return cert;}´

Comment: El certificado está, en principio bien instalado, con la clave exportable y en el almacen Personal. Se instaló igual en un W7 y ahí si que se recupera. Saludos.

Comment: a mi modo de ver deberías poner un pùnto de interrupción al inicio del bucle y verificar en cada iteración la variable `cert_aux` y comprobar sus propiedades.

Comment: Pero si ya el `certs.Count´ me devuelve 0, no me entra en el bucle.

Comment: Había pensado en temas de permisos para acceder a los certificados, pero me dicen en explotación que tengo los necesarios.

Comment: Si no tuvieras permisos suficientes te devolvería una `SecurityException`. Viendo esta parte de tu código `X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser)` veo que el almacén sobre el que estás buscando es el del Usuario no el de la máquina. Prueba a usar  `StoreLocation.LocalMachine`

Comment: gracias @Sergio, efectivamente era eso, pero no entiendo porqué en mi W7 funciona con el currentUser y en este servidor no. Instalamos el certificado con mi usuario de red, podría ser eso? el proceso puede estar intentando acceder a él con otro usuario? Ahora sin embargo, me devuelve este error: El conjunto de claves no existe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el almacén sobre el que estás buscando es el del Usuario no el de la máquina. Prueba a usar `StoreLocation.LocalMachine`
Si ejecutas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Eliges `Files/Add Remove Snap-in`y eliges `Certificates`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te sale la opción a elegir el almacén. Si eliges `My user account`, los certificados que instales sólo estarán disponibles para el usuario con el que te has identificado. Si eliges `Computer account` los tendrás disponibles para todos los usuarios identificados en la máquina (eligiendo `StoreLocation.LocalMachine`)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias @Sergio, lo he comentado a explotación, a ver si desinstalan el certificado y lo vuelven a instalar, porque ahí donde me has dicho, he visto que seguía estando el certificado anterior caducado, y es extraño, porque lo habíamos desinstalado... A ver si desinstalan todo y vuelven a instalar el correcto y vuelvo a probar. Saludos.

Comment: Pues nada, hemos desinstalado todos los certificado y vuelto a instalar el nuevo, pero sigue sin verlo. Desde el mmc que me comentas, tampoco lo ve, ¿puede ser porque el certificado lo emitió Camerfirma Corporate Server 2015? es lo único que veo diferente, el anterior era el típico  emitido por la FNMT. Saludos

Comment: Hola de nuevo y perdón por ser tan pesada, pero no hay forma. Sabes como puedo instalar el certificado para que esté en localMachine, para todos los usuarios.? si lo instalo con mi usuario, aún siendo administrador de la máquina, me lo pone en CurrentUser.

Comment: Has seguido los pasos de la respuesta? Elige la opción Computer Account cuando llegues a ella.

Comment: Bueno, al final lo he conseguido, importando el certificado desde el MMC en la máquina en vez de hacerlo directamente desde las opciones de Internet y después, desde aquí mismo, administrando las claves para dar permisos al usuario que lanza el WS y por fin!! Así que muchas gracias por todo @Sergio.

Comment: Puedes marcar la pregunta como respondida? Gracias

Comment: Perdona @Sergio, pero ¿como respondo? ya se que parece tonto pero no veo donde marcarla como respondida